# How to read SSE data in PHP

Tags: php, python

Need the code in PHP for a similar implementation that you can find below link in Python.

One of the 3rd Party server sends the data in SSE (Server Sent Events), that I need to be captured and save to my database in PHP.

I tried with HTML5 to read the stream and with AJAX call the data can be pushed to a PHP file in turn to DB. But the drawback is we have to keep browser on always.

I tried with `fopen` the streaming URL and `fread` to fetch data. But the looping and waiting for event data is where I struck. Need help in PHP code to read the data, so that I can set a cron job of the PHP code to push to DB as and when data receives.

Here is a Python code, I need a similar code in PHP
[Reading SSE data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022039/reading-sse-data-in-python)

Comment: [look](https://koditi.my/php-sse-example/)

Comment: That example is for creation of SSE in php and consume it in HTML page to show the data in webpage. But what I need is consume it in PHP with socket programming or so. So that the received data can be pushed to a database.

Comment: Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: comment the code ,that you create sse data!